How can I connect a node from one scene to another using a script in GODOT 4?
I have ParallaxBackground, Buildings and TileMap nodes from the first level scene. I will have several dozen levels. I also have a separate MiniMap scene. I want to connect the three aforementioned nodes to this scene using the script.
Here is my code at the moment:
extends SubViewport


@onready var camera = $Camera2D

var level_scene = preload("res://Scens/Levels/Level0/Level_0.tscn").instantiate() 
var Background
var Buildings
var Tile_Map
var level = Global.level:
    set(value):
        level = value
        Background = level_scene.get_node("ParallaxBG")
        Buildings = level_scene.get_node("Buildings")
        Tile_Map = level_scene.get_node("TileMap")

func _physics_process(_delta):
    camera.position = Global.player_position
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("action"):
        $".".add_child(Background)
        $".".add_child(Buildings)
        $".".add_child(Tile_Map)
        level = 1


I get the error "Invalid call. Nonexistent function 'get_node' in base PackedScene".
I'm still new to Godot 4. So I don't know how to solve this.

The error you're getting happens because a PackedScene instance does not directly have a child node like regular nodes, you need to instantiate the scene first to access its nodes. I'd suggest something like this:
extends SubViewport

@onready var camera = $Camera2D

var level_scenes = [
    preload("res://Scens/Levels/Level0/Level_0.tscn")
]
var current_level_scene = null
var Background
var Buildings
var Tile_Map

func _ready():
    load_level(0)  # Load the initial level

func load_level(level_index):
    if current_level_scene:
        current_level_scene.queue_free()

    current_level_scene = level_scenes[level_index].instantiate()
    add_child(current_level_scene)

    Background = current_level_scene.get_node("ParallaxBG")
    Buildings = current_level_scene.get_node("Buildings")
    Tile_Map = current_level_scene.get_node("TileMap")

func _physics_process(_delta):
    camera.position = Global.player_position

    # Example: Load the next level when a condition is met
    if some_condition:
        load_level(1)  # Load the second level

The best place to get the most updated information would be from Godot forums.

I didn't know about it. I will use it in future works. Thank you.
